# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in Managed Instance- Why?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to execute the following query in Managed Instance.

```
SELECT
T.name
FROM sys.tables T
WHERE T.name NOT IN ('ElsevierExtracts')
AND CAST(RIGHT(T.name,6) AS DATE) < DATEADD(DAY,-8,GETDATE())
AND T.type = 'U'
```

It throws an error as follows:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

The query is included in a SSIS Package in a Execute SQL task but comes up with an error because of the conversion.

Comment: can you post you table structure with data?

Comment: What does `T.name` look like?

Comment: You are querying the system table **`sys.tables`** which has info on ALL tables from your database. In my database I get names such as `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_UsersInRoles` (just an example). *Are you sure that it is enough to exclude just `'ElsevierExtracts'` when processing all those tables (probably not)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` instead of plain `CAST`

By using condition like `TRY_CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(T.name,6) ) < DATEADD(DAY,-8,GETDATE())` you will not get error for not matching table names.

Change your query like following.

```
SELECT
T.name   
FROM sys.tables T
WHERE T.name NOT IN ('ElsevierExtracts')
AND  TRY_CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(T.name,6) ) < DATEADD(DAY,-8,GETDATE())
AND T.type = 'U'
```

[**Online Demo**](http://%20https://rextester.com/IPD7929)

Comment: I am trying to execute the above query in managed instance but it comes up with the following error: 'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: Version is 12.0.2000.8

Comment: The error suggests that you are using database compatibility level less than SQL 2012, try running following command to set the correct compatibility level "ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;"

Answer (score 0):

Because table's `name` column data format is wrong.

ex:

```
select CAST(RIGHT('xxxx',6) AS DATE);
```

it'll get `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

you have to sure your data format like date,it looks like:

```
select CAST(RIGHT('20190218',6) AS DATE); --Run Success
```

---

**[Online Demo db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=abb81696007ab16ee5c33d96b621bfc7)**